# xinput map-to-output <device> <screen2> always pointing to screen1 on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, multiple-monitors, touchscreen

I have two screens, eDP-1 and VGA-1. The touch is a ILITEK with ID 11 on the "xinput list". My eDP-1 is the master one on the motherboard configuration (I can't change it), but I have to use the VGA-1 as primary, because is where I have the touchscreen. I've configured the monitors.xml, and with a mouse is working fine, but with the touch it's always pointing to the first screen (VGA-1).

I've run `xinput map-to-output 11 VGA-1` but the touch is always pointing to eDP-1.

I've tried to use `xinput set-prop` to change the Transformation Matrix, but it doesn't change its behavior no matter the Transformation matrix I set.

This only happens on Ubuntu 20.04. When I was using Ubuntu 16.04 it was working fine.

Comment: Sorry, when I said "he Touch is always pointing to the first screen (VGA-1)." I mean "he Touch is always pointing to the first screen (eDP-1)."

Answer (score 0):

Just after I post the question I've seen that there was two ID's for the same input device.
They where listed with ID 10 and 11.
After I repeat the input command to both of devices everything work very well.
So the answser is to make:

```
xinput map-to-output 10 VGA-1
xinput map-to-output 11 VGA-1
```

Thank you all anyway